# RAM backed File I/O

Tags: hard-drive, memory, cache

I have an HP laptop which parks its hard drive at the slightest bump, presumably detected by accelerometers. I'm glad it does this. I don't want horribly corrupted data. However, I have some pieces of software that will hang while the hard drive is parked because they rely on file I/O. Is there a (Windows) solution which will allow me to cache certain files in non-paged memory (physical RAM)? I want it so that when the heads park, the file is still available to those applications I do not want to hang.

Comment: SSD! please please just get an SSD already. Far more effective and reliable than any kind of esoteric caching gimmicks like ram-disks and special caching/replication apps that IMO routinely screw things up. Go SSD and I promise you'll be glad you did.

Comment: There are numerous programs that can create a RAMDrive, provided you put these files in the RAMDrive, it would get close to what you want.

Comment: Sounds like the HP drive guard software is a little to sensitive, try uninstalling HP drive Guard.